# Preventing bots: last user activity

Tags: php, security

I'm creating a website that has both commenting and voting systems. I wanted to prevent users (or bots) from clicking too much, by storing the last activity timestamp and if the last activity is less than 5 seconds, I show an error message to them. Currently I have implemented this in the MySQL DB but I'm thinking, I can move this to the session instead to improve performance. Which approach you think is better and why? Also, what other suggestions you have to prevent bots from spamming/putting load on my system?

EDIT:
Now that I think a little more about it, the session approach is not secure enough. Cookie is not either. A bot can remove the cookie and hit the server again.

Comment: What you want to reduce? Voting abuse or server load?

Comment: Well, if I can achieve the exact same result without the need to hit the DB, why not?

Comment: What result you want to achieve?

Comment: I wanted to prevent the user from voting rapidly (and abuse the server) As my edit says, I figured that the cookie approach is not secure enough.

Comment: So, storing IPs in the database is most robust solution. Once you experience any performance issues with it, you may move the ip's in some RAM-based storage, like memcachedb

Comment: Thank you. Using the memcachedb is an interesting approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the thing to the session will surely reduce the load of the bot server, making their job a lot easier.

> what suggestions you have to prevent bots from spamming/putting load on my system?

this is another question I believe.